# Prepared Statement lifetime and c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, prepared-statement, c3p0

I have a question about using prepared statements and a connection pool such as c3p0. I have a script running that interacts with my mysql database around once a second, ad infinitum. Each interaction executes a prepared statement. According to the documentation, a connection should be open and closed before and after a database interaction. My understanding is that the Connection object doesn't actually get destroyed, but added back to the pool. Since prepared statements are connection dependent, how do I use Prepared Statements without having to rebuild them every time that I get a connection from the pool - or do I just rebuild the statement after a connection is received by the pool and rely on the pool to do this efficiently via caching?

Comment: I have a feeling the correct answer would be to open the connection, build the prepared statement(s) that could be executed, close the statement every time it is time for my script to interact with the database. Would love some feedback on this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pool implements JDBC transparent Statement caching (as c3p0 does), you just use the ordinary JDBC PreparedStatement API and reuse of cached statements is handled for you.

Internally what happens is that when you call `conn.prepareStatement(...)` on some Connection, a lookup is performed on an internal hashtable using a key that includes the Connection's identity, the SQL text, and other characteristics of the requested prepared statement. If a suitable PreparedStatement is found, that is what is passed to the client. In none is, then the `prepareStatement` call gets passed to the Connection, and the returned PreparedStatement is cached for later reuse.

Statement caching itself has some overhead, and can be tricky to configure. Some newer Connection pools, most notably HikariCP, simply omit support, arguing that caching of PreparedStatements is better left to the DBMS. That, of course, is an empirical question, and will vary from DBMS to DBMS. If you do use Statement caching, the crucial point is that you need to allow for

```
[num_frequently_used_prepared_statments] * [num_connections]
```

distinct Statements to be cached. This is tricky to reason about, given the JDBC standard global `maxStatements` config property defines a global limit, even though PreparedStatements are scoped per-connection.

Much better, if you use c3p0, to set only the (nonstandard) [maxStatementsPerConnection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatementsPerConnection) property. That should be set to at least the number of PreparedStatements frequently used by your application. You don't have to worry about how many Connections will be open, since `maxStatementsPerConnection` is scoped per Connection like the Statements themselves are.

I hope this helps!

Comment: As Steve said (Hi Steve!) depending on the database, caching is also available at the driver level.  MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and others can do this just by specifying the proper driver properties.  The latest PostgreSQL driver is particularly efficient (exquisitely so).  Driver-level caching is independent of any pool, so you should feel free to use it even with c3p0.  Drivers like that provided by PostgreSQL is capable of sharing prepared statements *across* connections, so you can avoid some of the trickier tuning details and reduce your memory footprint at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. All of my statements are in the form of calls to stored procedures so configuring c3p0 to cache well won't be an issue. When I have a working product I will be optimizing with different DBs for different parts of the application at which point specific pool and driver optimizations will become more important.